# A secure transfer method for large XML file

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, xml, sftp, ftps

I have to put in place a transfer system to receive XML file of more that 1 Go.

This system have to be very secure.

I was about to take SFTP but it's not IIS compatible and some of the senders will probably have IIS servers and it's will add some time for the project to start.

There is no others options that to use FTPS ?

Comment: SFTP and FTPS are two unrelated protocols

Comment: I know, I was saying that FTPS is my only other solution but I don't find it sufficiently secure.

Comment: SFTP, as a protocol, is not more secure than FTPS. A different matter are the particular implementations.

Comment: Right, but in my case it's more "secure" if I can be sure of the client identity with a SSH key or a SSL cert.

Comment: I don't know if IIS supports it, but you should be able to use SSL client certificates when using FTPS in order to identify your users.

Comment: Actually, [FTP SSL Client Certificates <sslClientCertificates>](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/ftpServer/security/sslClientCertificates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS2 seems to be the answer !

You can have a SSL cert on the server and also on the client and you have MDN.

Comment: What's AS2 and MDN?

Comment: Sorry but I'm french, Wikipedia will explain it much better that me :) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS2

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) over HTTPS.